# Element broken on Safari for iOS

Tags: jquery, css, ios

I am experiencing a very frustrating bug on the following page with iOS: http://makethemostof.co.uk/test.html

There is a tab in the top right that says "Shopping Bag (empty)" that disappears on iOS. I have attempted to diagnose the issue with Firebug for iPad but can't seem to find the cause. I suspect it has something to do with the fact the element is position:fixed but I'm really not certain.

Does anybody know why iOS would behave this way when webkit on mac (and windows as far as I have seen) works just fine? What am I missing?

By the way there is also some jQuery acting on that area of the page (around line 100) which could also hold the cause of the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the overflow of the #bag element. I've set the overflow to be visible now and made changes directly to the contained elements to hide them. It's strange that this worked for all other browsers - it seems like iOS has the right interpretation of overflow:hidden in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The styling on it is forcing it to the right of the screen.

```
#bag-overview, #bag-close
...
margin: 0 0 0 720px;
...
```

is causing the issue sending it far to the right. Change this to something smaller to see the bar and you'll have to decide from there where to put it.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks for your response. It doesn't look like the margin is the issue. The element actually appears to be positioned correctly and I can see it move out of position when I change the margin values. Please see this screenshot of firebug on iPad to see what I mean: http://cl.ly/2j0J1m2d2p21021i0l2O The inspect tool is outlining the tab where it should be but I still can't see it.

Comment: the firebug console on the ipad seems to throw a question mark for the image file when pressing it in the css view, is the image being picked up on IOS? One good way to test this stuff is to out a thick border around the element your trying to check, if you see the border the element is there correctly and theres something else wrong like no image, if the borders not there it could be an issue with something like position fixed. Also thats only fully supported in IOS 5, you should check over devices or implement a different way is this will be an issue

Comment: Applying a red outline shows the top of the outline just about appearing.

Comment: the top just about appearing? is the rest appearing? could it be just a bit of the bottom showing and you need to move it down?

Comment: It was an issue with the overflow of the #bag element. I've set the overflow to be visible now and made changes directly to the contained elements to hide them. It's strange that this worked for all other browsers - it seems like iOS has the right interpretation of overflow:hidden in my opinion. Thanks for all your help Simon!